# Laravel returns a "unexpected $this" error when Model defines an eloquent relationship

Tags: php, eloquent, this

I have a Post table which refers to a User table. A user can have many posts, and a Post belongs to a User. I created all the tables, with the Post table having a user_id foreign key. I also created a Post Model like this :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        //dd($this->belongsTo("App\User"));
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
    }

}
```

The dd() dumps this :

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo {#282 ▼
  #child: App\Post {#286 ▶}
  #foreignKey: "user_id"
  #ownerKey: "id"
  #relationName: "user"
  #query: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#262 ▶}
  #parent: App\Post {#286 ▶}
  #related: App\User {#274 ▶}
  #withDefault: null
}
```

However I get a Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)

I don't understand why $this is not refering to the class itself and is not understood. Any clue ?
Thanks.

Comment: What's the file/line of that syntax error? are you sure it is thrown in the same file?

Comment: Can you add the full error message please? Also can you check that between `return` and `$this` there is no magic-character? Did you perhaps copy/paste the code from somewhere?

Comment: `I get a ... syntax error` - how/where?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers guys. Actually @ChristophKluge you were right, turns out there probably was a magic character dûe to a copy paste. VSStudioCode didn't manage it well as it displayed nothing... Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Actually @ChristophKluge was right, turns out there probably was a magic character dûe to a copy paste. VSStudioCode didn't manage it well as it displayed nothing... Thanks guys.

Comment: Glad I could help! By the way you can also upvote/mark comments as helpful. You can find the buttons/triggers left next to the comment. One for the upvote and another one (flag) if you want to report a comment.